# pandas python: access row by case insensitive label

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a df and I would like to access a row by label, but I would like the casing of the label to be ignored.

my df looks like this:

```
Name  exp1
Name      
Base  2074
Raw   2014
```

My failed attempt:

```
df.index.str.contains('base')
```

Note, I would like to avoid using the str.lower approach to solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work - need to convert the index to a Series first.

```
df[pd.Series(df.index).str.contains('base', case=False)]
```

Comment: is it possible to edit this to return the value? instead of a bool

Comment: See edit, just use the bools to index the dataframe.